How can we customize the Electron App title bar for windows, should contain minimal details such as the logo, name, mini, max, close
I am using vite+react for my project. I have setup and run the electron app. I was able to add the title and logo of my own. But i still want my title bar to be having few customization which makes a different from other. Help me to create custom title bar
I tried using the custom-electron-titlebar package but the documentation was not so clear enough.
Do we need to create any custom component for the titlebar or does it comes with default props as I'm already using a npm package.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
